# Can you explain this code and why we are passing the value of month decreasing it by one

Tags: java, java-calendar

> Can you Explain this java-Calendar code

`Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();`

`calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, month-1);`

> Why we are passing the value of month decreasing it by one

`calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, day);`

`calendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);`

`return calendar.getDisplayName(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, Calendar.LONG, Locale.US).toUpperCase();`

Comment: Probably changing from a one-based month (1-12) to a zero-based month (0-11).

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `Calendar`. That class is poorly designed and long outdated. Instead use `LocalDate` and `DayOfWeek`, both from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Comment: Instead of those 5 lines of code just do `return LocalDate.of(year, month, day).getDayOfWeek().toString();`. java.time is so much nicer to work with. And there’s no subtracting 1 or any other funny constant.

Answer (score 1):

## Avoid legacy classes

Among the many problems with the terrible old date-time classes bundled with the earliest versions of Java is their whacky numbering. Months of the year are numbered 0-11 for January-December.

Never use these legacy classes, `Calendar`, `Date`, etc.

## *java.time*

Use only *java.time* classes.

Apparently you want the current date.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "Africa/Tunis" ) ;
LocalDate today = LocalDate.now( z ) ;
```

If you want to switch month but keep the year and day-of-month, use [`withMonth`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalDate.html#withMonth(int)) method.

```
LocalDate ld = today.withMonth( Month.JANUARY ) ;
```

To quote the Javadoc:

> Returns a copy of this LocalDate with the month-of-year altered.
>
> If the day-of-month is invalid for the year, it will be changed to the last valid day of the month.

Since it seems that you want the name of the day of the week in uppercase in English, this is straightforward:

```
System.out.println( ld.getDayOfWeek() ) ;
```

> SUNDAY

`getDayOfWeek` returns a `DayOfWeek` enum constant. If you need a `String`, use its `toString` method.

Comment: Good answer. It’s either just `today.with( Month.JANUARY )` or just `today.withMonth( 1 )`.